# IEnumerable.GetEnumerator unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, fluent-assertions

My part of code:

```
    public class BinaryTree<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T> where T : IComparable
        {
.........

             public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
             {
                  return PreOrder().GetEnumerator();
             }

             IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

.........
```

I have test for GetEnumerator() method. This test work correctly:

```
[Fact]
        public void GetEnumerator()
        {
            BinaryTree<int> tree = new BinaryTree<int>();
            int exc = 5;

            tree.Add(5);
            IEnumerator e = tree.GetEnumerator();
            e.MoveNext();
            Object act = e.Current;

            act.Should().Be(exc);
        }
```

But how test this part of code??

```
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
```

Creates an explicit implementation of interface `IEnumerable`. To use it, you need to cast your object as an `IEnumerable`.

```
public void GetEnumerator()
{
    BinaryTree<int> tree = new BinaryTree<int>();
    int exc = 5;

    tree.Add(5);
    IEnumerator e = ((IEnumerable)tree).GetEnumerator();
    e.MoveNext();
    Object act = e.Current;

    act.Should().Be(exc);
}
```